# What is a better way to inference on chained machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, inference, accuracy

I'm trying to figure out a better way to make inference for my audio gender classification models.

I have created 2 models: (1) `model1` predicts adult/child, (2) `model2` predicts male/female.

My current approach is:

1. predict using `model1`, if "child", done, else continue
2. predict using `model2`, get "male" or "female"

If my `model1` has an accuracy (on validation) of 85% and my `model2` has an accuracy of 93%, then this is the expected accuracyfor my approach:

- child:
  $$P(model1\_correct) = 0.85 = 85\%$$
- male/female
  $$P(model2\_correct | model1\_correct) = \frac{0.93\times0.85}{0.85} = 0.93$$
  since two models are independent though chained
  $$P(model2\_correct) = P(model2\_correct | model1\_correct)P(model1\_correct)=0.93 * 0.85 = 0.79$$

Is the calculation above reasonable? However, in this way, my male/female confidence is much lower after adding child. Is there a better way I can use those 2 models for the 3-class classification?

Comment: What worries me about using two separate models here is that your child detector would probably be better with gender information. This makes me think that a single model performing the 3-class classification directly might be a better approach. Is there any particular reason why you're using two separate models?

Comment: @Jason I thought i mentioned this in the question but apparently I forgot. The first thing I tried is actually the 3-class classification model but it's not working well with the features that I'm using. The accuracy was only ~77%, that's why I decided to try this method.

Comment: Among other things, such error calculation would assume that the errors of the two models are independent of each other. That is rarely the case when two models are applied on the same dataset. I think using model stacking is more reasonable if you want to indeed have two models. That said, probably using more informative features will be more impactful (e.g. MFCC). Also notice that probably most of our mistakes would be in the `female`/`child` misclassification so you might want to focus there.

Comment: @usεr11852 I am indeed using MFCC as my feature. I actually haven't looked into the error confusion matrix, will take a look and see how it looks.